# is there an easy way to get the path for the subfolder?

Tags: path, operating-system

So my program gives the user the right to be able to create folders and subfolders...
So far I managed to make it creates the folder in a default directory but it get complicated for me when I try to create a subfolder...I have been trying to solve for hours now, but I cannot.
If someone can help me that would be very kool!!!
Their are comments on the code to help better understanding.
Thanks

```
import os
from os import listdir
from pathlib import Path

def display_menu(): #here is the menu for our display
    print("The File Manager program")
    print()
    print("COMMAND MENU")
    print("List - list all folders/subfolders/files")
    print("add - add a folder/subfolder/file")
    print("exit - Exit program")
    print()

def add(fm_list):
    msg = input("What do you want to create?: \n Insert 1 for Folder "
                "\n Insert 2 for Subfolder."
                "\n Insert 3 to choose a different location than DEFULT ")
    if msg == "1":
        folder = input("Name of the folder: ")
        fm_list.append(folder)
        os.chdir('F:\\Test')  # this path is our test path where folders and subfolders and files will be stored
        os.mkdir(folder)
        choice = input("Do you want to add a subfolder to this folder?: (y/n): ")
        if choice == "y":
            #In below, I have difficulties to make a path for the subfolder
            #I have tried all I know but nothing...
            #Instead of making the subfolder in the appropriate folder
            #it creates a folder
            subfolder = input("Name of the subfolder: ")
            fm_list.append(subfolder)
            os.chdir('F:\\Test\\')#HERE
            os.mkdir(subfolder)
            print(folder + " was added to the list of folder.")
            print(subfolder + " was added to " + folder)
        else:
            os.chdir('F:\\Test')  # this path is our test path where folders and subfolders and files will be stored
            #os.mkdir(folder)
            #os.chdir(folder)
            print(folder + " was added to the list of folder.")
            print("Your folder path is : " + str(Path.cwd()))  
def main():
    listdir(my_path)
    fm_list =[]
    display_menu()
    while True:
        command = input("Command: ")
        if command.lower() == "list":
            list(fm_list)
        elif command.lower() == "add":
            add(fm_list)
        elif command.lower() == "copy":
            copy(fm_list)
        elif command.lower() == "exit":
            break
        else:
            print("Not a valid command.\n")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the code you provided, I noticed that you create both the folder and the subfolder at the same level.

To create a folder, assuming that your sandbox is 'F:\Test' you write this :

```
 os.chdir('F:\\Test') # you changed your current directory to 'F:\\Test' (chdir means change directory equivalent to cd in linux shell)
 os.mkdir(folder) # you created a folder

 ... # after a few lines

 os.chdir('F:\\Test') # you're still in the same directory
 os.mkdir(subfolder) # folder and subfolder are thus created under the same directory
```

As you didn't change you current directory before creating the subfolder, you end up with two folders at the same level. Here's my suggestion.

The subfolder must be located inside a folder previously created under 'F:\Test'.

```
 os.chdir('F:\\Test') #changed the current directory to 'F:\Test'
 folder = 'Folder' # the name of the folder
 os.mkdir(folder)  # creates a folder inside 'F:\Test' and you get 'F:\Test\Folder'

 subfolder = 'Subfolder'

 # You need to concatenate 'F:\\Test' with the parent folder of your subfolder. I assume that you picked the previously created folder.

 os.chdir('F:\\Test\\' + folder) # changed the current directory to 'F:\Test\Folder'
 os.mkdir(subfolder) # creates a folder inside 'F:\Test\Folder' and you get 'F:\Test\Folder\Subfolder'
```

Comment: I really apreciate your help, this is great and does help me to finally create the subfolder....Kool